# Deleted default constructor. Objects can still be created... sometimes

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, list-initialization, aggregate-initialization

## The naive, optimistic and oh.. so wrong view of the c++11 uniform initialization syntax

I thought that since C++11 user-defined type objects should be constructed with the new `{...}` syntax instead of the old `(...)` syntax (except for constructor overloaded for `std::initializer_list` and similar parameters (e.g. `std::vector`: size ctor vs 1 elem init_list ctor)).

The benefits are: no narrow implicit conversions, no problem with the most vexing parse, consistency(?). I saw no problem as I thought they are the same (except the example given).

But they are not.

## A tale of pure madness

The `{}` calls the default constructor.

... Except when:

- the default constructor is deleted and
- there are no other constructors defined.

Then it looks like it it rather value initializes the object?... Even if the object has deleted default constructor, the `{}` can create an object. Doesn't this beat the whole purpose of a deleted constructor?

...Except when:

- the object has a deleted default constructor and
- other constructor(s) defined.

Then it fails with `call to deleted constructor`.

...Except when:

- the object has a deleted constructor and
- no other constructor defined and
- at least a non-static data member.

Then it fails with missing field initializers.

But then you can use `{value}` to construct the object.

*Ok maybe this is the same as the first exception (value init the object)*

...Except when:

- the class has a deleted constructor
- and at least one data members in-class default initialized.

Then nor `{}` nor `{value}` can create an object.

I am sure I missed a few. The irony is that it is called *uniform* initialization syntax. I say again: ***UNIFORM*** initialization syntax.

What is this madness?

### Scenario A

#### Deleted default constructor:

```
struct foo {
  foo() = delete;
};

// All bellow OK (no errors, no warnings)
foo f = foo{};
foo f = {};
foo f{}; // will use only this from now on.
```

### Scenario B

#### Deleted default constructor, other constructors deleted

```
struct foo {
  foo() = delete;
  foo(int) = delete;
};

foo f{}; // OK
```

### Scenario C

#### Deleted default constructor, other constructors defined

```
struct foo {
  foo() = delete;
  foo(int) {};
};

foo f{}; // error call to deleted constructor
```

### Scenario D

#### Deleted default constructor, no other constructors defined, data member

```
struct foo {
  int a;
  foo() = delete;
};

foo f{}; // error use of deleted function foo::foo()
foo f{3}; // OK
```

### Scenario E

#### Deleted default constructor, deleted T constructor, T data member

```
struct foo {
  int a;
  foo() = delete;
  foo(int) = delete;
};

foo f{}; // ERROR: missing initializer
foo f{3}; // OK
```

### Scenario F

#### Deleted default constructor, in-class data member initializers

```
struct foo {
  int a = 3;
  foo() = delete;
};

/* Fa */ foo f{}; // ERROR: use of deleted function `foo::foo()`
/* Fb */ foo f{3}; // ERROR: no matching function to call `foo::foo(init list)`
```

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882409/c14-value-initialization-with-deleted-constructor answers half the question. The most important one, but still doesn't answer what happens with in-class data member initializes and non-default constructors.

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty. Here, aggregate initialization is performed precisely because the constructor is defined as deleted (on its first declaration).

Comment: It isn't the single case of craziness in modern C++. For years I heard "C++ is silly as `static` means very different things depending on context" (actually there are only two very different meanings, and in clearly different contexts). Then `decltype` is invented with two subtly different meanings with a very subtle different use: `identifier` vs : `(identifier)`

Comment: "_no narrow implicit conversions_" And it's a good thing to disallow a perfectly valid and useful conversion in just one particular case?

Comment: @curiousguy I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @bolov "Narrowing" conversion is an obscure, ill defined concept (as is explicit conversion); and if you want to disallow a type of conversion, the only way is to do it everywhere. Disallowing something you don't like inside one particular syntax is nonorthogonal as well as illogical.

Comment: seems to be fixed in c++20: https://godbolt.org/z/Majaf6nTb

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When viewing things this way it is easy to say there is complete and utter chaos in the way an object is initialized.

The big difference comes from the type of `foo`: if it is an aggregate type or not.

> It is an aggregate if it has:
>
> - no user-provided constructors (a deleted or defaulted function does not count as user-provided),
> - no private or protected non-static data members,
> - no brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (since c++11 until (reverted in) c++14)
> - no base classes,
> - no virtual member functions.

So:

- in scenarios A B D E: `foo` is an aggregate
- in scenarios C: `foo` is not an aggregate
- scenario F:

  - in c++11 it is not an aggregate.
  - in c++14 it is an aggregate.
  - g++ hasn't implemented this and still treats it as a non-aggregate even in C++14.

    - `4.9` doesn't implement this.
    - `5.2.0` does
    - `5.2.1 ubuntu` doesn't (maybe a regression)

> The effects of list initialization of an object of type T are:
>
> - ...
> - If T is an aggregate type, aggregate initialization is performed. This takes care of scenarios A B D E (and F in C++14)
> - Otherwise the constructors of T are considered in two phases:
>
>   - All constructors that take std::initializer_list ...
>   - otherwise [...] all constructors of T participate in overload resolution [...]  This takes care of C (and F in C++11)
> - ...

:

> Aggregate initialization of an object of type T (scenarios A B D E (F c++14)):
>
> - Each non-static class member, in order appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the
>     initializer list. (array reference omitted)

---

**TL;DR**

All these rules can still seem very complicated and headache inducing. I personally over-simplify this for myself (if I thereby shoot myself in the foot then so be it: I guess I will spend 2 days in the hospital rather than having a couple of dozen days of headaches):

- for an aggregate each data member is initialized from the elements of the list initializer
- else call constructor

---

> Doesn't this beat the whole purpose of a deleted constructor?

Well, I don't know about that, but the solution is to make `foo` not an aggregate. The most general form that adds no overhead and doesn't change the used syntax of the object is to make it inherit from an empty struct:

```
struct dummy_t {};

struct foo : dummy_t {
  foo() = delete;
};

foo f{}; // ERROR call to deleted constructor
```

In some situations (no non-static members at all, I guess), an alternate would be to delete the destructor (this will make the object not instantiable in any context):

```
struct foo {
  ~foo() = delete;
};

foo f{}; // ERROR use of deleted function `foo::~foo()`
```

---

This answer uses information gathered from:

- [C++14 value-initialization with deleted constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882409/c14-value-initialization-with-deleted-constructor)
- [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)
- [List initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)
- [Aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)
- [Direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)

Many thanks to [@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m) who helped correct and improve this post.

Comment: could someone someone familiar with the standard please double check my answers to make sure I made no mistakes. I still don't fully grasp the complicated initialization rules. Thank you very much.

Comment: "no brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (since c++11)"  - this was reverted in C++14

Comment: You write "direct initialization" when you actually mean "non-aggregate initialization".  The term *direct initialization* refers to `T{a,b,c}` (and other situations) whether or not `T` is an aggregate.  All initialization is either *direct-initialization* or *copy-initialization*  (with further sub-classifications of those available).

Comment: I actually followed http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization . I know it's not a canonical reference

Comment: @M.M so why does gcc  4.9 and 5 treats F as non-aggregate in C++14 mode? Is it a bug?

Comment: Specifically , where you wrote "The effects of direct initialization (scenario Fb):" , you mean *non-aggregate*.  `Foo f{};` is direct initialization in all cases.

Comment: Scenario F is a non-aggregate in C++11, and aggregate in C++14.  g++ 5.1 correctly implements this; g++ 4.9.2 didn't

Comment: I tried with gcc-5.2.1 and it treats F as non-aggregate (error: use of deleted function)

Comment: See [C++11 aggregate initialization for classes with non-static member initializers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27118535/1708801) and [g++ 4.9 rejects valid aggregate initialization in C++14](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28113750/1708801) which covers some of @M.M comments.

Comment: C++17 is going to allow aggregates to have public bases, so you need to make `dummy_t` a private (or protected, but I don't see the point) base for that to work.

Comment: I recently had an odd bug with gcc 4.9 where replacing a deleted default constructor with an explicitly user defined one made a segfault 'go away'. My user defined one asserts if invoked. I did not look into the assembly code generated for this case but my guess is teething troubles with C++14 support (which is in any case incomplete on 4.9.3).

Comment: I would expand the example that turns your UDT into a non-aggregate by using _private_ inheritance. You wouldn't want to make it possible to select overloaded functions on this dummy type after all.

Answer (score 7):

What's messing you up is *aggregate initialization*.

As you say, there are benefits and drawbacks to using list initialization.  (The term "uniform initialization" is not used by the C++ Standard).

One of the drawbacks is that list initialization behaves differently for aggregates than non-aggregates. Also, the definition of *aggregate* changes slightly with each Standard.

---

Aggregates are not created via a constructor. (Technically they actually might be, but this is a good way to think of it). Instead, when creating an aggregate, memory is allocated and then each member is initialized in order according to what's in the list initializer.

Non-aggregates are created via constructors, and in that case the members of the list initializer are constructor arguments.

There is actually a design flaw in the above:  if we have `T t1;  T t2{t1};`, then the intent is to perform copy-construction.  However, (prior to C++14) if `T` is an aggregate then aggregate initialization happens instead, and `t2`'s first member is initialized with `t1`.

This flaw was fixed in a [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467) which modified C++14, so from now on, copy-construction is checked for before we move onto aggregate initialization.

---

The definition of *aggregate* from C++14 is:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

In C++11, a default value for a non-static member meant a class was not an aggregate; however that was changed for C++14.   *User-provided* means user-declared , but not `= default` or `= delete`.

---

If you want to make sure that your constructor call *never* accidentally performs aggregate initialization, then you have to use `( )` rather than `{ }`, and avoid MVPs in other ways.

Comment: IMHO this area of the standard needs improved. It'd be nice if classes could formally be marked as `aggregate` or non-aggregate, and perhaps also if the "aggregate-constructor" were formalized.

Comment: Or maybe get rid of aggregate classes altogether, i.e. treat all classes according to the non-aggregate rules.

Comment: I think the defect report was filed against C++11 so it could be fixed in C++14.

Comment: @5gon12eder see [CWG 1467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467).  C++14 was published without the fix; and then it was accepted as a defect in November 2014.  I'm not sure whether this means that it is considered to apply back to C++11 or not (possibly moot, as officially C++14 wholly replaces C++11, although compilers would have to decide what to do in `-std=c++11` mode)

Comment: Bjarne used the term so I went with it http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init Anyway good to know

Comment: "If we have `T t2{t1};` then the intent is to perform copy-construction." — Unless `T` is `std::vector<boost::any>`, in which case the intent is to initialize `t2` with an initializer-list whose single element is (a copy of) `t1`. This is the subject of [Core Issue 2137](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2137), which might get re-fixed in C++17 if we're lucky. (It was fine in C++11, then broken in C++14.) If you literally must have copy-construction, the syntax for that is `auto t2 = t1;`.

Comment: @Quuxplusone argh...   That workaround isn't always possible, e.g. if we're going via perfect forwarding

Comment: If you're writing a function that perfect-forwards its arguments to `T`'s constructor, then the best practice to reduce the user's confusion is to follow the same practice as `vector<T>::emplace` (i.e. `allocator<T>::construct`) and `make_shared<T>` — which is `T t2(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` with parentheses instead of braces. If `foo(args...)` constructs a `T` via perfect forwarding, that construction had better execute exactly the same code as `T(args...)` or else the user will get *very* confused.

Answer (score 6):

These cases around aggregate initialization are counter-intuitive for most and was the subject of the proposal [p1008: Prohibit aggregates with user-declared constructors](http://wg21.link/p1008) which says:

> C++ currently allows some types with user-declared constructors to be initialized via aggregate
>   initialization, bypassing those constructors. The result is code that is surprising, confusing, and
>   buggy. This paper proposes a fix that makes initialization semantics in C++ safer, more uniform,
>   and easier to teach. We also discuss the breaking changes that this fix introduces

and introduces some examples, which overlap nicely with the cases you present:

> ```
> struct X {
>     X() = delete;
>   };
>
>  int main() {
>     X x1;   // ill-formed - default c’tor is deleted
>     X x2{}; // compiles!
> }
> ```
>
> Clearly, the intent of the deleted constructor is to prevent the user from initializing the class. However, contrary to intuition, this does not work: the user can still initialize X
>   via aggregate initialization because this completely bypasses the constructors. The author could even explicitly delete all of default, copy, and move constructor, and still fail to prevent the client code from instantiating X via aggregate initialization as above. Most C++ developers are surprised by the
>   current behaviour when shown this code
>   The author of class X could alternatively consider making the default constructor
>   private. But if
>   this constructor is given a defaulted definition, this again does not prevent aggregate initialization (and thus, instantiation) of the class:
>
> ```
> struct X {
>   private:
>     X() = default;
>   };
>
> int main() {
>     X x1;     // ill-formed - default c’tor is private
>     X x2{};  // compiles!
>   }
> ```
>
> Because of the current rules, aggregate initialization allows us to “default-construct” a class even if it is not, in fact, default-constructible:
>
> ```
>  static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible_v<X>);
> ```
>
> would pass for both definitions of X above.
>
> ...

The proposed changes are:

> Modify [dcl.init.aggr] paragraph 1 as follows:
>
> > An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 12) with
> >
> > - **<s>no user-provided,  explicit</s>**, **u̲s̲e̲r̲-̲d̲e̲c̲l̲a̲r̲e̲d̲** or inherited
> >       constructors (15.1),
> > - no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 14),
> > - no virtual functions (13.3), and
> > - no virtual, private, or protected base classes (13.1).
>
> Modify [dcl.init.aggr] paragraph 17 as follows:
>
> > [Note: An aggregate array or an aggregate class may contain elements of a class >>type with a **<del>user-provided</del>** **u̲s̲e̲r̲-̲d̲e̲c̲l̲a̲r̲e̲d̲** constructor (15.1). Initialization of >>these aggregate objects is described in 15.6.1. —end note]
>
> Add the following to [diff.cpp17] in Annex C, section C.5 C++ and ISO C++ 2017:
>
> > C.5.6  Clause 11: declarators              [diff.cpp17.dcl.decl]
> >
> > **Affected subclause**: [dcl.init.aggr]
> >     **Change**: A class that has
> >     user-declared constructors is never an aggregate.
> >     **Rationale**: Remove
> >     potentially error-prone aggregate initialization which may apply
> >     not withstanding the declared constructors of a class.
> >     **Effect on original feature**: Valid C++ 2017 code that aggregate-initializes a
> >     type with a user-declared constructor may be ill-formed or have
> >     different semantics in this International Standard.

Followed by examples which I omit.

The proposal was [accepted and merged into C++20](https://twitter.com/timur_audio/status/1006540660453924866) we can find the [latest draft here](http://eel.is/c++draft/) which contains these changes and we can see the changes to [[dcl.init.aggr]p1.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1.1) and [[dcl.init.aggr]p17](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#17) and [C++17 declarations diff](http://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp17.dcl.decl).

So this should be fixed in C++20 forward.

Comment: it seems it is fixed in c++20: https://godbolt.org/z/Majaf6nTb