# Using an overloaded operator to perform operations at time of function call?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to figure out how I can perform an operation at the time in which a function is called, for example:

```
ExampleClass eco;
eco.DoStuff();
```

At the point of `eco.DoStuff()`, I'd like to log to a file.

I'm trying to get something with overloaded operators but with no luck?

E.g.

```
void operator>>(ExampleClass eco, std::function<void(void)> DoStuff) 
{
 //Perform logging into a file
 DoStuff;
}

int main()
{
  ExampleClass eco;
  std::function<void(void)> func_pointer = std::bind(&ExampleClass::DoStuff, &eco, 2);
  eco >> func_pointer; 
}
```

This works, however I can't use a flexible parameter for `DoStuff`, as this has to be explicitly set in `func_pointer`.

Additionally, creating function pointers for every single method in my class isn't an option.

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a templated definition for the output operator?

```
template<typename Function>
void operator>>(ExampleClass eco, Function DoStuff) 
{
 //Perform logging into a file
 DoStuff();
}
```

---

A possible variation on this method is to supply functors to the `operator>>` overload that take `eco` as an lvalue argument:

```
template <typename MemberCall>
ExampleClass& operator>>(ExampleClass& eco, MemberCall mem_call){
    eco.log();
    mem_call(eco);
    return eco; // returned lvalue eco allows chaining
}
```

Ease of use could be improved by creating a helper function to convert member function pointers and arguments to functors taking an `ExampleClass` lvalue argument:

```
template <typename MemberFunctionType, typename...Args>
auto member_call(MemberFunctionType mem_fn, Args&&...args){
    return [=](ExampleClass& object){
        return (object.*mem_fn)(args...);
    };
}
```

to be used like so:

```
eco
    >> member_call(&ExampleClass::DoStuff, 2)
    >> member_call(&ExampleClass::DoStuff, 4);
```

It should be noted that the errors should you supply an invalid argument to this construct may not be pretty, since `member_call` returns lambdas. If it becomes a problem, creating and returning a custom functor type will likely improve error message quality.

Comment: An added benefit of this method is that instead of using `std::bind`, you may simply do `eco >> [&](){eco.DoStuff(2);};`

Comment: Is there an approach that avoids having to make the `eco.DoStuff` explicitly in `int main`.. E.g. `eco >> DoStuff(22);` ? Isn't this solution also just using a template, where I still have to use a `std::bind`?

Comment: Are you only going to be using member functions with the same number of arguments?

Comment: No, the class' member functions have a variety of arguments.

Comment: You have to specify the arguments you're going to supply to the function somehow. There *are* ways to shorten it, though.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fe1b0e637e40a83). This is essentially the same idea as above, except it uses functors that take a single argument of type `ExampleClass`, and offers a helper function to generate those functors. (Not adding as different answer for that reason, actually) And it uses the operator chaining so happily (ab)used by iostreams.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Well, that might be a good extension to add up in my answer. I left binding to the `eco` parameter open. I'm going to mark that as community wiki answer now, feel free to improve it.

Comment: If you decide to use the linked method in any extensive way you'll probably want to make a custom functor class to try to improve the error messages you'll get--applying the wrong type to a functor returned by a templated function with an `auto` returned lambda is...unlikely to be pretty.

Comment: @jaggedSpire You may add a separate answer as well, giving you a chance to gain rep.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ edited. (Thanks, but I'm not too attached to gaining rep these days.)

Comment: @jaggedSpire You've got spine. I appreciate and respect this most in these days of darkness.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you.

Comment: I'll defer that bounty as soon it's possible.

Comment: I don't know what to say. Thank you, again.

Comment: @jaggedSpire I'm referring [to that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618213/when-is-a-private-constructor-not-a-private-constructor). That's meant as an incentive for you.