# c++11 value-initialization prior to aggregate-initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, aggregate, language-lawyer, value-initialization

I try to understand the first accepted answer of @bolov to the question [Deleted default constructor. Objects can still be created... sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988297/deleted-default-constructor-objects-can-still-be-created-sometimes) [1]

It seems like I found a error there and so it messes up the whole explanation.

@bolov explains why this code SUCCEED to be compiled in c++11:

**Scenario A**

```
struct foo {
  foo() = delete;
};

// All bellow OK (no errors, no warnings)
foo f = foo{};
foo f = {};
foo f{}; // will use only this from now on.
```

And why this code FAILS to be compiled in c++11:

**Scenario C**

```
struct foo {
  foo() = delete;
  foo(int) {};
};

foo f{}; // error call to deleted constructor
```

He says that the point is that the first one foo is an aggregate and the second one foo is not an aggregate.

Then he gives the excerpt from cppreference:

> The effects of list initialization of an object of type T are:
>           ...
>
> - If T is an aggregate type, aggregate initialization is performed. This takes care of scenarios A B D E (and F in C++14)
> - Otherwise the constructors of T are considered in two phases:
>
>   - All constructors that take std::initializer_list ...
>   - otherwise [...] all constructors of T participate in overload resolution [...] This takes care of C (and F in C++11)
>       ...

According to the excerpt when you write *foo f { };* in **scenario A** you get aggregate-initialization. An it would be great. But in reality in c++11 (#3337 draft, closest to standard) you have **different initialization order**:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - If the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.
> - Otherwise, if T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1)

So *foo f { };* in **scenario A** should result in value-initialization, that is, the DELETED default constructor will be called and the code should fail to be compiled.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Tried to make it more concise.

Comment: @Quentin, okay, I will try to write better.

Comment: @Quentin, I have rewritten my question.

Comment: Very nice, that improved it a lot ! I'm a bit lost in the different initializations, but the [cppreference page for value initialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) states, before any description, that "In all cases, if the empty pair of braces `{}` is used and T is an aggregate type, aggregate-initialization is performed instead of value-initialization.".

Comment: @Quentin, thank you very much for the link! It would be great if this phrase is true but I fail to find this phrase in standard. :( I will try to search better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a result of [Core Issue 1301](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1301), which was a defect against C++11, the precedence for list-initialization changed from:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - If the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.
> - Otherwise, if T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1)

to:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - If T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed (8.5.1)
> - Otherwise, if the initialize list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.

So `foo{}` in Scenario A is still aggregate-initialization.

Comment: Yes, I understand BUT this change was in #3367 draft and it was accepted to C++14. But in Wiki I read that the draft #3337 is closest one to c++11. So in c++11 we DON'T have the change and so it looks like compilers when compiling as c++11 should not consider Scenario A as aggregate-initialization, am I right?

Comment: @JenyaKh Issue 1301 was a defect against C++11, so a conforming C++11 compiler should implement the change.

Comment: @JenyaKh defect reports are backwards-applied onto the corresponding standard. They're patch updates, if you will :)

Comment: This answer is outdated, but correct when it was written -- see [p1008](http://wg21.link/p1008)