# Creating an empty std::array of non default initializable types

Tags: c++, visual-c++, default-constructor, stdarray

I have a class `A` that is non default initializable that I can't modify.

How can I create a length zero std::array containing said class?

This works in both clang and gcc but not MSVC.

```
#include <array>

struct A {
    A(double, int) {};
};

using Empty = std::array<A, 0>;

inline const Empty GetChildren() {
    return {};
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const Empty& test(GetChildren());
    for (const auto& a : GetChildren()) {}
}
```

Comment: What's the point of creating a const empty array?

Comment: Could you please specify how it does not work? Do you have an error message?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44815242, this is supposed to work, and the fact that MSVC doesn't compile it is either a bug in the standard for not being clear enough in allowing it, or a bug in MSVC. It means any answer you'll get will be a workaround that involves not actually using `std::array<A, 0>`.