# Why does this temporary created with deleted constructor compile?

Tags: c++, temporary-objects, aggregate-initialization, deleted-functions

This code:

```
struct F
{
    F() = delete;
    void foo() {};
};

int main()
{
    F{}.foo();
}
```

Live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b720eb750ac7970a).

Suffice to say I would assume it to not compile (as we're calling a deleted constructor). Why does it compile on any compiler I've tried?

I've noticed that not using uniform initialization, compiling the code will result in [the expected error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50ac956e2227a4fc).
So why is it that the (aggregate?) initialization is still allowed in the presence of a deleted constructor?

Comment: It looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988297/deleted-default-constructor-objects-can-still-be-created-sometimes

Comment: It's an issue in C++17 - C++20 fixes it. [Here's the parer](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf).