# Default constructor of T is bypassed when {} are used with new to create std::array<T, n>

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, compiler-errors, new-operator

Let's consider this class:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A() = delete;

    A(int i) :
            i_m(i) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << i_m << '\n';
    }

    ~A() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << i_m << '\n';
    }

private:
    int i_m{1234567890};
};
```

The default constructor is explicitly deleted so AFAIK `A` can only be constructed from an integer. The default initialization of data member `i_m` will never be used.

Let'ts consider this program:

```cpp
int main() {
    using T = std::array<A, 2>;

    //T a;
    // error: use of deleted function 'std::array<A, 2>::array()'
    // note: 'std::array<A, 2>::array()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed
    // error: use of deleted function 'A::A()'

    //T b{};
    // error: use of deleted function 'A::A()'
}
```

Again, this seems completely fine to me.

Let's now consider this other program:

```cpp
int main() {
    using T = std::array<A, 2>;
    auto foo = new T{};
    delete foo;

    auto foo_init = new T{1, 2};
    delete foo_init;

//  auto zorg = new T();
//  delete zorg;
//  error: use of deleted function 'std::array<A, 2>::array()'
//  note: 'std::array<A, 2>::array()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
//  error: use of deleted function 'A::A()'

    auto zorg_init = new T({3, 4});
    delete zorg_init;
}
```

This code *does* compile (with no warning) and generates the following output:

```
A::~A() 0
A::~A() 38870160
A::A(int) 1
A::A(int) 2
A::~A() 2
A::~A() 1
A::A(int) 3
A::A(int) 4
A::~A() 4
A::~A() 3
```

And now something seems *not* fine to me. How it that possible that the line `auto foo = new T{};` is not considered ill-formed? The initialization of class `A` is completely bypassed here.

It is worth nothing that this code doesn't compile:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto p = new A{};
    delete p;
}
```

The error being the expected:

```
error: use of deleted function 'A::A()'
```

I tested those codes with the following options: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++17`. `gcc -v` gives: `gcc version 7.2.0 (x86_64-posix-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)` on my computer.

Any explanation will be greatly appreciated :)

---

PS : after exhaustive tests in Compiler Explorer (using with sample https://godbolt.org/z/5VZLU_), it seems that this is an issue in gcc 7.x. Indeed, only 7.x versions of gcc compile this sample. gcc 6.4 doesn't not. gcc 8.1 neither. clang neither. msvc neither.

Can you confirm that there is no UB here and this is really a compiler bug?

Comment: Do you have a typo `auto p = new A{};`? Shouldn't it be `auto p = new T{};`?

Comment: @NutCracker my bad `using T = std::array<A, 2>;` was not supposed to be in the last program. I really want to allocate an `A` to show that the issue is here only when using `std::array`. I have updated my question.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleted default constructor. Objects can still be created... sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988297/deleted-default-constructor-objects-can-still-be-created-sometimes)

Comment: @NutCracker No, `A` isn't an aggregate in this case.

Comment: @NutCracker it doesn't because I can't create objects as shown in this discussion, because I have private fields. The point of my question is why `new T{}` is the only case where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `T b{};` doesn't compile while `new T{}` makes it evident that this is a compiler bug anyway.  However, the standard itself is probably defective.  Here's why.

---

The technical answer to this question is: the code is **well-formed**, because the standard specifically says so. [[array.overview]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/array.overview#2)

> An `array` is an aggregate that can be list-initialized with up to `N`
>   elements whose types are convertible to `T`.

The initializer `{}` indeed contains "up to `N` elements whose types are convertible to `T`" — it contains 0 elements, [all of which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) are convertible to `A`.

---

How are the elements initialized then?  The standard isn't really clear on this.  Here's what [[array.overview]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/array.overview#3) says:

> An `array` satisfies all of the requirements of a container and of a
>   reversible container ([container.requirements]), **except that a
>   default constructed `array` object is not empty** and that `swap` does
>   not have constant complexity. [...]

(emphasis mine)

The standard does not mention how the elements of this non-empty `array` are initialized.

---

Suppose that `std::array` is implemented like this (for `N == 2`):

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
struct array {
    T __elem[N];
};
```

Then the elements are copy-initialized from `{}` according to [[dcl.init.aggr]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#8):

> If there are fewer *initializer-clauses* in the list than there are
>   elements in a non-union aggregate, then each element not explicitly
>   initialized is initialized as follows:
>
> - ([8.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#8.1)) If the element has a default member initializer ([class.mem]), the element is initialized from that initializer.
> - ([8.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#8.2)) Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, **the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list ([dcl.init.list]).**
> - ([8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#8.3)) Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.
>
> [...]

which is ill-formed according to [[dcl.init.list]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#3) (the deleted default constructor is selected).

This means that the standard considers the common implementation to be wrong, which is probably not intended.